# Find Trace of the Matrix $P^4 - P^3.$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, trace

Let $P$ be a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix such that Trace(P) = 1, Determinant(P) = -6, Find Trace$(P^4 - P^3).$

What I have done, if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ is the eigen value, then I find $\lambda_1 = 3$ and $\lambda_2 = -2.$ So the eigen value of $P^4$ will be 81 and 16. From this point we can find Trace$(P^4).$ Similarly for Trace$(P^3).$ So we can find the desired result.

My question is am I right? Also What is the role of complex matrix here?

Comment: This looks good to me. The complex field plays almost no role, but the question setter has to specify the ground field anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By application of [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), we have
$$P^2-P-6I=0$$
Thus
$$\text{Trace}(P^2)=\text{Trace}(P)+6\,\text{Trace}(I_{2\times 2})=13$$
On the othe hand
$$P^3=P^2+6P$$
therefore
$$\text{Trace}(P^3)=13+6=19$$
and
$$P^4=P^2+12P+36I^2$$
so
$$\text{Trace}(P^4)=13+12+72=97$$

Comment: Or write $x^4 - x^3 = (x^2+6)(x^2-x-6)+6x+36$ and so $P^4 - P^3 =6P+36I$

Comment: Yes exactly....